# Alternatives to var_export

Tags: php

`var_export` function causes an exception while argument has circular references. Are there any alternatives (except `serialize`) which handle it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Are you looking for **[var_dump](http://var_dump)** or even **[debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)**</strike>

**Update:**

**[Converting object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016271/convert-an-object-to-a-string-in-php)**

Comment: I want to convert object to string. var_dump outputs it, I don't need this

Comment: @darja: The only other way i know of is serializing it (although you say except it). See my updated answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for link. It sounds that I have two variants - serialize (which I don't want) and json_encode.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this :

```
ob_start();
var_dump($var);
$dump = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And why can't you use serialize ?

Comment: I need such converting for logs. And serialize output is too ugly for logs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 $backtrace = array_slice( debug_backtrace( 0 ), 0, 6);

 $export = var_export( $backtrace, TRUE );
```

You might need to tweak the slice amount so that it cuts out the circular reference. I had this issue while trying to do a var_export() on an exception while running a PHPUnit test.