# What does this error shows? Object of class Hide could not be converted to string

Tags: php

i have this code

```
class  Hide {

    private $myname;
    function getmyname()
    {
        $myname = __class__;
        return $myname;
    }
}

class  damu {
    private static $name;
    public function name()

    {
    var_dump($this->name);
        if( $this->name == null ){
               $this->name = new Hide();
          }
          return $this->name;
    }
}

$run = new damu();
echo $run->name();
```

this giving me an error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Hide could not be converted to string

what is the meaning of this and how to resolve this.

Comment: Which line does the error occur in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be returning

```
return $this->name->getmyname();
```

or define a tostring for the Hide class

```
public function __toString() {
     return "str";   }
```

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to echo a Hide() object, which PHP doesn't know how to convert to a string. This is due to the following lines:

```
        if( $this->name == null ){
           $this->name = new Hide();
      }
      return $this->name;
```

and then

```
echo $run->name();
```

Instead of echo, try

```
print_r($run->name());
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you can hook into the magic function `__toString` which PHP tries to call when you echo an object.

Answer (score 4):

You return an instance of `Hide` and try to echo it. Since your implementation does not have a `__toString()` method, there is no string representation and you get that error. Try this:

```
$run = new damu();
echo $run->name()->getmyname();
```

or add a `__toString()` method to `Hide`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an instance of the class `Hide`

```
if( $this->name == null ){
  $this->name = new Hide();
}
return $this->name;
```

and then you try to echo that instance here:

```
echo $run->name();
```

`echo`, expects a string. That's why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

As *Christopher Armstrong* said, you're trying to use a *Hide()* object as a string, and PHP doesn't know how to convert it.
You could, however, try to convert it to a string using this code:

```
$myText = (string)$myVar;
```

Wich I found here: [ToString() equivalent in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098/php-tostring-equivalent/28111#28111)

I also found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016271/convert-an-object-to-a-string-in-php/1016281#1016281) that may help you.